# How to speed up neofetch? Alternatives or neofetch caching

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, alternative

I've configured my terminal in a such a way that it runs `neofetch` when opened.
However, there is now, a 200ms (approx.) delay before i can start typing.

Are there any faster **alternatives** to `neofetch` or is it possible to **cache neofetch's output** periodically?

Comment: Take a look at [this Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/ep2jue/why_is_neoftech_slow/) that explains why `neofetch` is slow, and how to speed it up.

Comment: Instead of having it show in every terminal, I would bind it to a shortcut key, for instance having Ctrl+N run Neofetch. The syntax is a little special though: `bind '"\C-n"':"\"neofetch\C-m\""`

Comment: @cocomac That fix seems to be rpm specific, and won't work in Ubuntu.

Comment: If you cache, then you won't get the correct value of uptime. If you really want to cache, then rather copy the output, remove the bits about no. of packages and uptime, and print that static output in .bashrc. You can change the output when you modify the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, you can comment out information about the number of packages in `$HOME/.config/neofetch/config.conf` (or for some specific case, in `/etc/neofetch/config.conf`) like this :

```
#    info "Packages" packages
```

Comment: Neofetch configuration is not stored in `/etc` as far as I can see.

Comment: @Someone The location of the `.../neofetch/config.conf` configuration file can change. It depends on how you installed `neofetch`. Did you install `neofetch` via a package manager or manually ?

Comment: `sudo apt install neofetch`. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: @Someone My bad, I have two different ubuntu systems with one I installed neofetch from a previous Launchpad PPA. For a normal Ubuntu, the `neofetch` config file must be in `$HOME/.config/neofetch/config.conf`

Comment: Check `dpkg -L neofetch` for the system wide or default location. On 18.04, it should be in `/etc/neofetch/neofetch.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Try [Archey](https://github.com/HorlogeSkynet/archey4), it runs instantly for me.